# threshold a region in the iamge only when the region is larger than 10 pixels

Tags: image, matlab, noise, connectivity, threshold

How should I threshold (denoise) the image that has multiple regions with white regions. I have make make the white religions all 1s, but I want only the regions that is at least 10 pixels (or I think some number of pixels connected ) as 1s, and make those regions that is less than 10 pixels all 0s.

For example, in figure 1, the top regions is about 20 pixels large, and the bottom is about 5 pixels. How should I do an automatic way to make all the pixels in the bottom region 0s.

[image]

Comment: First threshold, then select connected components based on size. See `bwareaopen`.

Comment: Maybe you can use regionprops command.